# Is there a way to play videos from where it's stopped previously in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-video-player

I want to play the video from the exact time where it's stopped previously in flutter video player. Is there a function or a dependency with which I can do it?

Comment: Please share some code of your aproaches.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to resume playing if application is still in memory that means user os OS did't clear your application data from RAM you can use any state management solution [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider), [Bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) to store Video's current position in every second or any interval.

On the other hand if you want to resume video's from recent position even when your app isn't opened from for cache (User or system cleared app's cache from Ram) you should use any persistent storage plugin [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) for instance.
this is the general solution of solving this problem you should search for how to implement those plugins in your app.